# unable to configure any security with basicHttpbinding in wcf test client

Tags: c#, wcf

I've been working with wcf library project and I cannot test my project in wcf test client with security settings for basicHttpBinding either message or transport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SoapUI, it is a proper tool for testing wcf services in both http & https mode
the site is:
http://www.soapui.org/
you can see tje feature here:
http://www.soapui.org/About-SoapUI/features.html